# Problem with InsertImage() function in Appscript, (Invalid image data exception)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I'm automating some forms using Appscript and I'm having a invalid image data exception thrown everytime I have a image that's a somewhat bigger than 25000000 pixels^2. I tried somethings but It didn't work out. Here's the code:

```
function replaceTextToImage(body, searchText, image, width) {
  var next = body.findText(searchText);
  if (!next) return;
  var r = next.getElement();
  r.asText().setText("");
  var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, image);

  if (width && typeof width == "number") {
    var w = img.getWidth();
    var h = img.getHeight();
    img.setWidth(width);
    img.setHeight(width * h / w);

  }
  return next;

}

function getImageLinks(text){
  
  var linkArray = text.toString().split(", ");
  console.log(linkArray);
  linkArray = linkArray.map(getOnlyId);
  console.log(linkArray);
  return linkArray;
}

function replacePhotosBasedOnList(text, listOfPlaceHolders, body, width){
 
  var listOfLinks = text;
  var count;
 
  if(listOfLinks[0] != ""){
    for (count = 0; count < listOfLinks.length; count++){
      var image = DriveApp.getFileById(listOfLinks[count]).getBlob();
      replaceTextToImage(body, listOfPlaceHolders[count], image, width);
    }
  }
  for(var i = count; i < listOfPlaceHolders.length; i++){
    body.replaceText(listOfPlaceHolders[i], '')
  }
  
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about resizing the image before the function `replaceTextToImage is run? When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(listOfLinks[count]).getBlob();
```

#### To:

```
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w${width}&id=${listOfLinks[count]}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
```

- In this case, the image is resized using your `width`.
- If the same issue related to the large image size occurs again, please test the following modification. In this case, as a sample, the limit width is 1000 pixels.

  ```
    var twidth = 1000;
    var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w${twidth}&id=${listOfLinks[count]}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
  ```

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for answering my question. The thing is whenever I try to run my script (after the modifications suggested) I get the exception "You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch". I already did a json file and put some oauthscopes there such as the one that UrlFetchApp requires and its still not working. Do you have any idea of what's happening?

Comment: @Isabella Sampaio Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I already did a json file and put some oauthscopes there such as the one that UrlFetchApp requires and its still not working.`, if you are setting the scopes using `appsscript.json`, can you provide your current values of it? Or, if you are not required to use `appsscript.json`, how about removing `"oauthScopes": [,,,]` and testing it again? By this, the required scopes are automatically detected by the script editor.

Comment: So, change the appscript.json (took oauthScopes out) and I'm still getting the problem. My file looks like this now btw {
  "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
  "dependencies": {},
  

  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}

Comment: @Isabella Sampaio Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `So, change the appscript.json (took oauthScopes out) and I'm still getting the problem.`, can you provide the current error message? Because when I tested your script without setting the scopes to `appsscript.json`, no error occurs. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. As of the error message I'm still getting the same one from the first comment "Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch", even after the changes I did at appscript.json like said in my other comment

Comment: @Isabella Sampaio Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch`. So, for example, when you create a new Spreadsheet and copy and paste the script including my proposed script, and test it again, what result will you obtain?